# changing the background color of sencha touch panel

Tags: touch, extjs

I am trying to change background color of panel.

Please see the code:

```
panel: {
            centered: true,
            width: 200,
            height: 150,
            style: 'background-color: red',
            fullscreen: false,
            hidden: true,
            zIndex: 10,

       }
```

but ***style: 'background-color: red'*** statement doesn't fulfill my requirements. it changes the color of panel border only not complete panel background color.

please suggest for the same.

thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This works for me in 2.0.0:

```
Ext.application({
    launch : function() {
        Ext.Viewport.add([{
            xtype: 'panel',
            style: 'background-color:#F00'
        }]);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

This link: http://www.sencha.com/forum/archive/index.php/t-108823.html

Suggests that background-color is its own entity. I've never actually used Sencha, but a group I was working with considered using it once... e.g.

```
panel: {
        centered: true,
        width: 200,
        height: 150,
        background-color: red,
        fullscreen: false,
        hidden: true,
        zIndex: 10,

   }
```

also, I don't know if that's for an older version you're not using.

Comment: Yes, this is older version of sencha, i am using sencha 2.0 version. I used same thing in my code but it's not working.  thanks for sharing anyway!!